# Error 400 when making post request to API created with Flask in Python

Tags: python

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import pandas as pd
import ast
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Mail(Resource):
    # methods go here
    def get(self):
        data = pd.read_csv('mails.csv')  # read CSV
        data = data.to_dict()  # convert dataframe to dictionary
        return {'data': data}, 200  # return data and 200 OK code
def post(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  # initialize

    parser.add_argument('address', required=True)  # add args
    parser.add_argument('plain', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('html', required=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()  # parse arguments to dictionary

    # create new dataframe containing new values
    new_data = pd.DataFrame({
        'address': args['address'],
        'plain': args['plain'],
        'html': args['html']

    })
    # read our CSV
    data = pd.read_csv('mails.csv')
    # add the newly provided values
    data = data.append(new_data, ignore_index=True)
    # save back to CSV
    data.to_csv('mails.csv', index=False)
    return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200  # return data with 200 OK

def delete(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  # initialize
    parser.add_argument('address', required=True)  # add userId arg
    args = parser.parse_args()  # parse arguments to dictionary
    # read our CSV
    data = pd.read_csv('mails.csv')
    if args['address'] in list(data['address']):
        data = data[data['address']] != args['address']

        # save back to CSV
        data.to_csv('mails.csv', index=False)
        # return data and 200 OK
        return {'data': data.to_dict()}, 200
    else:
        return 404





api.add_resource(Mail, '/mail')
app.run()
```

From another script I'm making the request like so: requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/mail?address=1@1.com&plain=1&html=1')
I can't figure out what is wrong, it returns 400 every time. Any help would be much appreciated. CSV file that I'm trying to write to is empty. GET reqeust finishes fine.

Comment: Your code does not declare the functions inside the class. Maybe that’s just copy paste issue?

Comment: Yes sorry copy paste error @William

Comment: try placing a breakpoint and see if it hits your method to begin with

Comment: Tried removing the post method and it responded with error 405 instead @drum

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger? And did you check the logs?

Comment: My understanding is that Flask has no log by itself. Use a debugger how? I’m not very experienced. @drum

Comment: download pycharm and use that to debug

Answer (score 0):

I created a try except block and fixed the return statement of the function if it failed and found out that the error was the way the Pandas dataframe was created.